# Como eu faço a conta de avaliação

Tags: php

To ficando louco aqui já tentando descobrir como eu faço a conta para obter resultado pra mim fazer uma progress bar desse jeito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ali na barra de 5 estrelas tem 100% na de 4 tem 20% como chego nesses resultado.

Divisão ??
Eu conseguiu o resultado daqueles 4,4 ali, mais para cada barra eu não estou conseguindo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisas de saber:

- pontuação máxima possível
- quantidade de votos
- qualidade de votos

Em variáveis poderia ser:

```
$quantidadeVotos = 15 + 3 + 2;
$qualidadeVotos = 5*15 + 4*3 + 1*2;
```

assim sendo que a pontuação máxima é 5, e pensando que a pontuação máxima seria `$quantidadeVotos * 5`, podes fazer:

```
$quantidadeVotos * 5     5
____________________  = ___

  $qualidadeVotos        ?
```

Então podes resolver com:

```
$resultado = $qualidadeVotos / $quantidadeVotos;
```

ou seja, neste exemplo que deste:

```
$resultado = (5*15+4*3+1*2) / (15 + 3 + 2); // 4.45
```

Comment: Consegui.. dividi a quantidade de votos em 4 estrelas por exemplo e dividi pelo total de votos pra consegui a % de cada barra de progresso